# Forge API - Design Automation Inventor 2022 compatibility

Tags: automation, autodesk-inventor

I cannot upload Inventor 2022 files into Forge design Automation system. is there any compatibility issue with 2022?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose which **Inventor** engine you want to use in your **Activity** on **Design Automation** by setting the `engine` parameter when creating it:

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/activities-POST/

You can check which product versions are available using this endpoint:

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/engines-GET/

The reply which includes **"Autodesk.Inventor+2022"**:

```
{
"paginationToken": "3eyJOYW1lX2xhYmVsIjp7IlMiOiIzZHNNYXguMjAyMSJ9LCJSZWNlaXZlciI6eyJTIjoiZXZlcnlvbmUifSwiT3duZXIiOnsiUyI6IkF1dG9kZXNrIn19",
"data": [
"Autodesk.3dsMax+2020",
"Autodesk.Inventor+2022",
"Autodesk.AutoCAD+24_1",
"Autodesk.Inventor+2019",
"Autodesk.AutoCAD+22",
"Autodesk.AutoCAD+23_1",
"Autodesk.Inventor+23",
"Autodesk.AutoCAD+24",
"Autodesk.Inventor+2020",
"Autodesk.Revit+2021",
"Autodesk.AutoCAD+23",
"Autodesk.Inventor+2021",
"Autodesk.Inventor+24",
"Autodesk.AutoCAD+prerelease",
"Autodesk.Revit+2018",
"Autodesk.Test+Latest",
"Autodesk.Inventor+22",
"Autodesk.AutoCAD+21",
"Autodesk.Revit+2019",
"Autodesk.3dsMax+2021"
]
}
```

The second page of the reply:

```
{
"paginationToken": null,
"data": [
"Autodesk.Revit+2022",
"Autodesk.AutoCAD+20_1",
"Autodesk.Inventor+2018",
"Autodesk.3dsMax+2022",
"Autodesk.Revit+2020"
]
}
```